# Windows Forms Datagridview, get column name

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I want to check if my datagridview column has a specific name when clicking on a cell.

lets say i have

```
Name Prename
A    B
C    D
```

and I just want to check if my `Prename` cell got selected.

I tried sth like `if (datagridview.SelectedColumns.ToString() == "Prename") {action}`
but it doesn't work, should be really easy but I am blind.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a DataTable as the DataSource.  It is easy to get the names from the DataTable.

Comment: U can make use of CurrentCell to get current selected cell.

Comment: The datatable behind the view is very confusing and has more rows than the view itself. So want to get the colum of the selected cell.
No I cant use the CurrentCell.

Comment: To get at the [DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=netcore-3.1) use this, maybe in the CellClick event:  `datagridview.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName`

Comment: What is the selection mode you are using "DataGridViewSelectionMode"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want to know which cell is selected, the subscribe cell click event and check the column name as follows. refer @Taw comment for more info.

```
    private void datagridview_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isPrenameSelected = ((DataGridView)sender).Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName == "Prename";
        if(isPrenameSelected)
        {
            //more code here
        }
    }
```

if you want to know selected cells then u can subscribe the SelectionChanged event. Check the selected cell with specific criteria as follows

```
   private void datagridview_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool isPrenameSelected = ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells
                            .Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Any(x => x.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName == "Prename");
    }
```